# How to make another app show notifications in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am creating a fake call application that writes to the call log, when I add a missed call to the log, even though the call is registered l there is no missed call notification, neither on the lock screen or the notification bar, how can I force the default phone app to show notifications? I was thinking of maybe restarting the phone app but I think I would need root access for that?

Right now I am using NotificationManager to show notifications like this:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

b.setContentTitle(name);

b.setContentText("missed call");

nm.notifiy(1001, b.build());
```

This works but I want the default phone app to do it.

Comment: check if the default phone app gives you a service to do that. if that app gives a service like that then only you can do it. and in my knowledge the default phone app does not provide such service.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only the application is allows it (due to security reasons). You need to find a documentation\sources, maybe application allows it using by intent system.